# jenkins 2.0 pipline println not working

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Given this FirstScript.groovy:

```
class FirstScript implements Serializable{
    def firstFunction() {
        println "This print doesn't work"
        return "This string can be returned and printed"
    }
}

return new FirstScript()
```

And this pipline code:

```
node("Slave") {
    checkout scm
    def firstScript = load 'FirstScript.groovy'
    echo firstScript.firstFunction()
}
```

The only output is "This string can be returned and printed".

This obviously happens because println happens on the slave's output stream and not on the master's, but I need a way to continuously print things from the slave to the master's console log.
Tried passing System.out from master to slave, had no effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

heh, it wasn't obvious to me why println wasn't working, but good call, that makes sense. if you have a bunch of shared code to write, you probably want to use a [jenkins shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). you can use `echo` within vars in a shared library.

if you want to make your example work "as is," you could inject the pipeline context into firstFunction:

FirstScript.groovy:

```
class FirstScript implements Serializable{
    def firstFunction(dsl) {
        dsl.echo "This print doesn't work. well now it does. :)"
        return "This string can be returned and printed"
    }
}

return new FirstScript()
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
node("docker") {
    checkout scm
    def firstScript = load 'FirstScript.groovy'
    echo firstScript.firstFunction(this)
}
```